# Block url with specific code after ".html"

Tags: .htaccess, query-string

Hello I´m receiving strange visits (just one or two per day) asking for urls from my site but followed with stranges code that doesn't exit in the site. For example:

`example.com/anypost.html&ved=2ahUKEwiig8DIkJuAAxU7CrkGHZ5cAJIQFnoECFoQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2dhpfeXlap0oBtncRYFbjb` where someone is adding `&ved=blablabla`.

Also, they asked for `&ea=whatever`; `&fwr=whatever`; `&region=whatever`; `&crui=whatever` where *whatever* is a crazy amount of things without sense that obviously are related with any spamming or sql injection.

So, how can I block these specifics code. Any idea?

Comment: Can you please clarify the URLs in question. The supposed example you have used does not actually contain a query string (there is no `?`). Also, are the `**` part of the URL, or is that an attempt at formatting? It is clearer to just format the URL as code without additional formatting/emphasis. Are any of these "URL params" used by your site at all? Depending on what URL params your site uses (if any), it might be easier (and more furture proof) to whitelist the allowed params instead of blacklisting the ones you don't?

Comment: Sorry, is not a parameter "?", is it an add after .html with "&ved=whaterver" or "&ea=whatever". My fault... This is the code that this strange ips add to the url: 

**&ved=2ahUKEwiig8DIkJuAAxU7CrkGHZ5cAJIQFnoECFoQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2dhpfeXlap0oBtncRYFbjb**

My page doesnt use & after urls. Seems to be an injection or similar. So i want to block all hits that add "&ved=whatever", "&ea=whatever"; "&fwr=whatever"; "&region=whatever"; "&crui=whatever"

Comment: Is this a static site where `/anypost.html` is a physical file? Is `/anypost.html` a valid URL that is perhaps passed to a front-controller? Presumably these URLs already result in a 404 response?

Answer (score 0):

> Block url with specific code after ".html"
>
> My page doesnt use & after urls.

(To clarify, there is no query string here as there is no `?`.)

It doesn't sound like you need to be particularly "specific". Blocking any URL-path that simply contains `.html&` would seem to be sufficient.

This can be achieved using mod_rewrite at the top of the root `.htaccess` file.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule \.html& - [R=404]
```

The above forces a 404 (Not Found) response for any request that contains `.html&` in the URL-path. I would think this is better than a 403 (Forbidden) in this situation (it's not like you are "protecting" something).

However, these requests should already be returning a 404, so this doesn't really achieve much, except possibly failing early and preventing the request being passed to a front-controller?

Although if this is a static site (ie. `anypost.html` is a physical file) then this is not really doing anything extra and should probably be removed.

Comment: Yes they are returning a 404, the problem is that there are too many hits with this "html&' codes in seconds and sometimes the server freezes for a minute or more (high resources cpu and ram). That's why I want to block when any of these ips (different ranges also) asked for them. I think its some kind of injection or spamming or hacking.

About just removing the file you calle "anypost.html". Hits with this stranges codes are not related to the same url, they asked for any html so the problem couldnt be solved removing a simple post from my site.

Comment: @RalAMORESGONZLEZ "there are too many hits with this "html&' codes" - in your question you said "just one or two per day"? Did the code in my answer help? As I mentioned, "failing early" could relieve pressure on on your application/resources. If not then you would likely need to implement a (hardware) firewall in front of your application server.

Comment: @RalAMORESGONZLEZ "the file you calle "anypost.html"" - I used the generic `anypost.html`, since that what _you_ used in the question. Yes, I assumed that meant "any" post and was not a literal name. I did _not_ suggest removing this file (or post) from the site.. How are requests routed on your site? Is your site essentially static `.html` files or do you have a front-controller/CMS type site?

Comment: I´m not understanding you as well as I want. Look, halfa and hoy ago some ip from Peru ask for a post from my site. The petition comes from google ok? It look like a common visit but no. After entering in the post, then this ips ask for THEURL.HTML at least 50 times of more (at the same and next seconds) adding the "&whatever" code. So that amount of requests that gives a 404 makes my server fall for a minute or 2.

I´m using a common wordpress site. When i said a couple of times per day I´m referring to "this crazy amount of visits adding code happens one or two time per day"

Comment: So, sending the request which add "&whatever" to a 404 its not going to help cause they get into the site by the google search site. Seems to be a real visit but I´m sure they are not cause in the followed two seconds the crazyness of adding "&whatever" starts. That´s why I just want to block them. Changing 404 to 403 in your suggested code would block them?